# Proving that $\left(\frac{1}{10^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is $0.1$-steady

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

Is the following proof correct? The Definition of $ε$-steady is given below.

**Proposition**. The sequence $\left(\frac{1}{10^n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is $0.1$-steady.

*Proof.* Let $j,k\in\mathbf{Z}^+$, furthermore let $x=\max(j,k)$ and $y = \min(j,k)$ consequently $y=x+r$ for some $r\in\mathbf{Z}^+$. Now Consider the following $$d(j,k) = d(x,y) = \left|\frac{1}{10^x}-\frac{1}{10^y}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{10^x}-\frac{1}{10^{x+r}}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{10^x}\right|\cdot\left|1-\frac{1}{10^r}\right|.$$
Now since $x,r\in\mathbf{Z}^+$ consequently $a=\left|\dfrac{1}{10^x}\right|\leq \dfrac{1}{10}$ and $b=\left|1-\dfrac{1}{10^r}\right|<1$ thus $ab\leq\dfrac{1}{10}$. Since our choice of $j,k$ was arbitrary it follows that $d(x,y)\leq 0.1,\forall j,k\in\mathbf{Z}^+$.

$\blacksquare$

> **Definition**. A sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is $ε$-steady if and only if Given a $\epsilon>0$ we have$$d(j,k) =
>  |a_j-a_k|\leq ε,\forall j,k\in\{n\in\mathbf{N}|n\ge m\}.$$

Comment: Is your sequence $\{1/10, 1/10, 1/10, ...\}$ or something else?  And why does the definition start at some index $m$?  What is $m$?

Comment: @Michael I apologize for my slopiness let me make some corrections.

Comment: Looks like your definition (and proof) are over-complexified? It sounds like $\epsilon$-steady means that $|a_i-a_j|\leq \epsilon$ for all $i,j \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, which certainly holds for $\{1/10^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $\epsilon=1/10$ since all numbers in that sequence are between $0$ and $1/10$.  In your proof you can just use $i,j$ and without loss of generality assume $i \leq j$.

Comment: The question is admittedly weird , is there any mistake (or mistape) ?

Comment: @Pagode I assure you there is no mistake

Comment: @AtifFarooq ok no problem , just want to help if you're in trouble

Comment: Oh I was reading the title !!

Comment: So it makes sense

Comment: @Pagode Thanks for your Edit!

Comment: You're Welcome Naturally.